# Using wp_trim_words and got 'registering custom post type is a plugin territory' in all post excerpt

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach

inside my custom loop, i used `foreach()` to show the latest posts in one of my template part called content-latest.php, and it was working fine before i added `wp_trim_words()` to show some excerpt into the loop, and its getting text output says "*registering custom post type is a plugin territory...*" in every post. The thumbnails, the titles is normal but not with the excerpt. The same is going with `the_excerpt()`.

This is my codes before added the excerpt(and working but no excerpt):

```
    <?php 
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts();
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
    if($recent['post_status']=="publish"){
    if ( has_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"])) {
        echo '<li><div class="media">
            <a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="'.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" class="media-left">' 
            .   get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"], 'thumbnail').'</a> <div class="media-body">
            <a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]). '" 
            class="catg_title" style="color:#000000;">' .esc_attr($recent["post_title"]). '</a></div></div></li> ';
      }else{
        //something here.. 
            }
         }
    }
    ?>
```

code after:

```
<?php 
        $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts();
        $trim = wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 7, '...' );
        foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        if($recent['post_status']=="publish"){
        if ( has_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"])) {
            echo '<li><div class="media">
                <a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="'.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" class="media-left">' 
                .   get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"], 'thumbnail').'</a> <div class="media-body">
                <a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]). '" 
                class="catg_title" style="color:#000000;">' .esc_attr($recent["post_title"]). '<br>' . esc_attr($trim) . '</a></div></div></li> ';
          }else{
            //something here.. 
                }
             }
        }
        ?>
```

note that i assign the `wp_trim_words` to `$trim` and calling it as the excerpt. I am under learning process so i don't know why or how to handle this. can someone kindly explain to me?

Answer (score 0):

get_the_content need a post id to work.

```
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
   $trim = wp_trim_words( get_the_content($recent['ID']), 7, '...' );
}
```

Comment: thank you for the the explanation, but i still get the same result.. please look at this pic [here](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=25um793&s=9#.V-kIs1V96ig). 
i've search for the reason, one from [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/219745/how-can-i-fix-those-issues-generated-by-the-themecheck-plugin) and i think this type of loop should not be added directly in template part, is it?

Comment: Where do u register the post type ?

Comment: And do u user your own theme ?

Comment: no, i'm not registering it as any post type and yes, i develop my own template.. i was thought this type of loop can be added as general type of loop directly into the template part but it's not, i get this code from [here](http://officetricks.com/display-recent-posts-with-thumbnails-without-plugins/) and modified it for my needed.